# Node voltage equation with weird solutions

Tags: circuit-analysis, homework, nodal-analysis

I recently had an exam with the following multiple choice problem:

> Consider the circuit below:

> [image]

> The node voltage equation for node A is which of the following?:

> 1. \$ \frac{V_A-kV_a}{R_1}+ \frac{V_A-V_3}{R_2} + \frac{V_A-V_B}{R_6} = 0 \$

> 2. \$ \frac{V_A+kV_A}{R_1} + \frac{V_A-V_3}{R_2} + \frac{V_A-V_B}{R_6} = 0 \$

> 3. \$ \frac{V_A-kV_A}{R_1} + \frac{V_A+V_3}{R_2} + \frac{V_A+V_B}{R_6} = 0 \$

> 4. \$ \frac{V_A+kV_A}{R_1} + \frac{V_A+V_3}{R_2} + \frac{V_A+V_B}{R_6} = 0 \$

> 5. \$ \frac{2V_A}{R_1} + \frac{V_A+V_3}{R_2} + \frac{V_A+V_B}{R_6} = 0\$

> 6. \$ \frac{V_A-V_3}{R_2} + \frac{V_A-V_B}{R_6} = 0\$

**My attempt**

This is how I would make the node voltage equation for node A:

\$ \frac{V_A}{R_1} + \frac{V_A-V_3}{R_2} + \frac{V_A-V_B}{R_6} + ki_1 = 0 \$

But as you can see, it doesn't match any of the options above and I can't figure out how I'm supposed to reach on of those solutions.

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: fix i1 to i2 in your eq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tricky case.

V3=(I1-I2)R3. Va=-(I1)R1. With these you can fade the controlled current source from your equation.